# Add memory device to QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, qemu, mmap, dma

I want to extend the current QEMU implementation with a custom DRAM device, that has a memory controller and with a more detailed physical view (row/banks).

The idea is that every memory access to the memory area handled by this device should pass through the controller. In addition, the user application should also be able to interface to the device via Loadable Kernel Module to send custom commands to the device itself.

For example:

```
int *array = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));    
// somehow map to the device memory area (easier if it's the only dram device)

array[10] = 1;                            
// goes to the device controller that sets the value internally

device_set_value(array, 2, 1); 
// performs array[2] = 1 but by passing through the kernel module that writes 
// this command to the driver MMIO.
```

I started by looking at the `edu.c` in https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.7.0/hw/misc/edu.c
and the sample kernel module proposed here

https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/6788a577c394a2fc512d8f3df0806d84dc09f355/kernel_module/pci.c

But I don't think that in this way a CPU access in QEMU would pass through the driver. The driver only reacts to values written into the MMIO registers.

One way could be to send a custom command for every operation to the device, but this would discard all C operators like pointer dereferencing.

In addition, how can the module translate from user virtual to physical addresses? Because if it has to perform DMA to access the actual memory (as done in edu device), it needs a physical address. I have seen that it might be done via the mmap() call implemented as file_operation in the loadable kernel module, but I couldn't find an example online.

Thank you in advance

Comment: PCI devices have a config space that is used to read and write to their controllers.

Comment: isn't that the same thing as what I called MMIO?

Comment: "But I don't think that in this way a CPU access in QEMU would pass through the driver. The driver only reacts to values written into the MMIO registers.": not sure I understand, doesn't the driver write to the MMIO registers with`iowrite32`? Which is triggered for example by `write` operations from userland to the device file? About DMA, I got lazy and didn't learn how to do it, if anyone learns, a pull request or link to working code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it does with `iowrite32`, but that would be on the MMIO register. If the device has a separate memory or has to access to the main memory directly via DMA, it needs a physical address on where to access. So one problem in my view is to pass the physical address in the `write`/`iowrite32`. The other is that (assuming the memory managed is the DRAM) if the CPU wants to directly access memory, the request won't pass through the device controller, because the CPU will access the QEMU MemoryRegion directly. Does it make sense?